# apostrophe truncating value in input field

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

I have an input box on a page which is reloaded via ajax call (content is refresh). The problem is when the input box has a single quote in it the remaining value is truncated, how can I fix that problem?

```
myVal = <-- its coming dynamically from db and when it contains values like "It's me", next time page reloads It just show "It" in input box
$('#myInput').val(myVal);
//after setting value and doing some other things, this content is reloaded
```

here is the java (server side code)

```
<input id="myInput"  value="<c:if test='${deamer!=null}">${deamer.name}, ${deamer.code}</c:if>' />
```

the code fails when from the server side value has ['] in it....

Comment: Well, if you write on this page in a javascript console `$('.textbox').val("123'3\"")` you'll see that the right value is set for the search field. Can you show a fiddle reproducing that error?

Comment: It's probably getting truncated before you set it with `val`. Post your code where it comes from the db, it's probably there

Comment: question updated with java code...

Answer (score 2):

You're having a problem with escaped strings. This is important to be aware of, as improper handling of string escaping can result in being potentially exposed to XSS and injections attacks.

Since you haven't provided any code, nor specified what language you are using on the server side to insert the DB values on the script, you cannot be helped much farther. I would advise against inserting raw data like this, and use some form of intermediary, such as a server response in the form of JSON, which can be consumed by javascript quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce the problem:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   myVal = "It's me"
   $('#myInput').val(myVal);
});
```

Text in input is It's me.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pMAj4/)